# Getting unsupported operand type(s) error for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' while defining a recursion function

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, typeerror, nonetype

So I was supposed to write a function `reverseWrd` which uses recursion to reverse individual words in a string, for example `reverseWrd("Hello it's me")` returns `olleH s'ti em`. I wrote the following code but it gave an unsupported operand type error.

```
def reverseWrd(sentence):
    if i=="":
        return i
    else:
        return reverseWrd(i[1:]) + i[0]
```

**Edit**: I have changed my code as I just realized that I can not use loops for this question. But this code reverses the whole string. Any suggestions on how to reverse just individual words?

Answer (score 0):

**ANALYSIS**

The problem is in the base vs recursion logic.  The base case handles a null string, and the recursion (`else` part) handles a string of length 2 or more.

When you get down to a the base case, i[1:] and i[0] aren't as flexible as you imagine.

**REPAIR**

Instead, make a simple change to you `if` statement:

```
if len(i) <= 1:
```

Now, you successfully reverse a word.

**FURTHER WORK**

If you're supposed to reverse an entire sentence, why do you split it into words, and reverse only the first one?  Perhaps you need an outer function that will do the split into words, and an inner function that the outer one calls.  The inner function reverses a single word.

Comment: But wouldn't running a for loop iterate over every word in the list?

Comment: No `for` loop will automatically do exactly what you want; you have to program it correctly.  The one you wrote in your original posting returns as soon as it's done with the first word.